# Identify subelements related to a sku in a separate table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I guess the best way to describe my question is to show you the inputs and outputs.

With the table:

| Variant | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Tiger_1 | 1 |
| Tiger_2 | 1.2 |
| Tiger_3 | 1.5 |
| Tiger_4 | 0.8 |
| Lion_1 | 2.1 |
| Lion_2 | 3.2 |
| Lion_3 | 0.2 |

I want to create a table that, given the column in the left, autofills de values for the column in the right.

| Animal | Variants |
| --- | --- |
| Tiger | Tiger_1;Tiger_2;Tiger_3;Tiger_4;Tiger5 |
| Lion | Lion_1;Lion_2;Lion_3 |

Basically, given a table of subelements and a table of indices, I want to get a list, for each index, of the subelements that belong to it.
I know about the search function to identify if "Tiger_1" contains "Tiger", but I would need to do that iteratively for the whole table, and don't know how to :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I ask because newer versions of Excel have worksheet functions that make doing this sort of thing easier.

Comment: Version 2105 (build 14026.20334)

Comment: to get you started: `ARRAYTOTEXT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether the formula is helpful.

`=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(LEFT($A$2:A$8,FIND("_",$A$2:$A$8)-1)=A12,$A$2:$A$8,""))`

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!
I had to change the condition of the IF formula, as my actual elements contain more that one "_", and that made it not work - I replaced it with a IFERROR(SEARCH(index,range),-1)>0.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with pivot table (works in Office 365)

- add a helper column with your main category, formula:
  `=LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2)-1)`
- insert a pivot table, make sure you check "add this data to the data model"
  [image]
- move your category to rows
- in power pivot tab select measures - new measure
- enter this formula then press OK
  `=CONCATENATEX(Range,[Variant],",")`
  [image]
- add your measure in values part of pivot table

[image]

Comment: I went with another answer that didn't use pivot tables, but this solution seems cleaner and I'll try to organize it this way in the future, thanks!